How to keep decimal places in branca colormap using folium?
I'm using branca to create a custom color map to use in a folium map. I would like for the scale to display the decimal places from the index still, not round to a whole numbers, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. Below is a snippet of some of the code I'm using.
`
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm

def create_scale():
    output_colormap = cm.StepColormap(["#ffffcc","#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4","#2c7fb8","#253494"],
                       index= [0.0,
                               10.0,
                               30.0,
                               50.7,
                               69.8,
                               92.1,
                               100.0
                              ],
                       vmin=0.0,
                       vmax=100.0) 
    return output_colormap

def style_function(feature,colormap,measure):
    value = feature['properties'][measure]
    if value is not None:
        fill_color = colormap(value)  # Convert color value to string
    else:
        fill_color = 'gray'
    return {
        'fillColor': fill_color,
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 1,
        'fillOpacity': 0.7
    }

def create_map(measure):
    
    colormap = create_scale()
    map = folium.Map(location=[30, 0], zoom_start=2)
    folium.GeoJson(
        geojson_test,
        name='geojson',
        style_function=lambda feature: style_function(feature,colormap,measure)).add_to(map)

    svg_style = '<style>svg#legend {background-color: GhostWhite;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;}</style>'
    map.get_root().header.add_child(folium.Element(svg_style))

    colormap.add_to(map)
    
    return map

Here is what I get when I run this on a a randomly generated geojson with random values assigned.

I have tried making sure the index is a float variable as well as searching for solutions form others, but have not yet found a solution to this issue.
